# Adapting csv reader to read unicode characters

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm having a problem with characters in a csv file coming through as the black diamond with a ? in the middle.

I have written the code to parse the csv, but I don't get why the string isn't reading the unicode characters properly. It's probably something to do with my implementation:

```
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path)

try {
  while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null) {
    string[] row = { "", "", "" };
    int currentItem = 0;
    bool inQuotes = false;
    if (skippedFirst && currentItem != 3) {
      for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++) {
        if (!inQuotes) {
          if (line[i] == '\"')
            inQuotes = true;
          else {
            if (line[i] == ',')
              currentItem++;
            else
              row[currentItem] += line[i];
          }
        } else {
          if (line[i] == '\"')
            inQuotes = false;
          else
            row[currentItem] += line[i];
        }
      }
      parsedFile.Add(row);
    }
    skippedFirst = true;
  }
```

Comment: if `readFile` is a `StreamReader`, you could use the constructor with encoding part: `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: Show the creation of `readFile`.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Put it as an answer! That helped out brilliantly

Comment: @danrhul Glad to be of help ;) A little bit late, and that was a guess - there's already an answer like that, just accept it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify the Encoding when opening the File.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\Temp\csvfile.csv", Encoding.UTF8)) {
}
```

You might also want to look into Filehelpers for CSV parsing:

https://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart/

Comment: Are you sure that the csv is utf8 encoded? Maybe it's something different. Latin1 or something like that. The problem with encodings is that you *have* to know what it is, as it is impossible to detect it properly.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was something like Encoding.GetEncoding(1212)